# How to install python modules from sources onto a virtual environment

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, python-module

As I understand it you install a module from sources with pip install -e /my_module

When I do this pip show -f my_module | grep Location
 gives ~/my_module as the location instead of my virtual environment's site-packages

I have my virtual environment activated when I install the module. I've also tried moving my module's folder into my virtual environment's site-packages but it installs it in site-packages/my_module instead of just site-packages.

I am doing this so that I can edit an existing module to work with my data's shape.

What is the correct way to install a module from sources onto a virtual environment?

Answer (score 1):

> As I understand it you install a module from sources with pip install -e /my_module

No, not exactly. `pip install -e` installs in "editable", i.e. development mode. Instead of copying installed files into `site-packages/` directory `pip` configures `site-packages/` and your sources so that python imports your modules from you source directory. That way you can edit the modules and the changes are immediately available to python. Without `-e` pip would install the package in the usual way — by copying it to `site-packages/` so if you edit your code you need to reinstall.

> When I do this pip show -f my_module | grep Location gives ~/my_module as the location instead of my virtual environment's site-packages

Yes, that's how `pip install -e` works. If you want your code to be copied to virtual environment's `site-packages/` don't use `-e`.

> I am doing this so that I can edit an existing module to work with my data's shape.

Then you certainly need `-e` so that your modules can be imported from the source directory.

> What is the correct way to install a module from sources onto a virtual environment?

Both `pip install` and `pip install -e` are correct, they are for different use cases.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Removing -e did make it install in the correct place. Now if I do pip show -f my_module | grep Location with my module or with an existing working module they both give the same location. The problem is that my module still isn't getting imported when I run my python file! I thought the problem was that it wasn't getting installed in the right place, but it must be something different. Any ideas on why the module isn't getting imported?

Comment: Don't forget to reinstall every time when you edit sources.

Comment: Sorry I accidentally posted my comment before asking a follow up question which is: The problem is that my module still isn't getting imported when I run my python file! I thought the problem was that it wasn't getting installed in the right place, but it must be something different. Any ideas on why the module isn't getting imported?

Comment: You better ask a different question with more details — where the package is installed, what files are there, what's the error, results of `which pip`, `which python`, `pip --version`, `python --version`.

Comment: Ok I found a problem but it didn't lead to a solution. For some reason virtualenv --system-site-packages ~/venv
installs python 2.6 instead of 3.6. I fixed the problem and now everything is in python 3 but it's still not able to find my module. I have venv activated and when I use ~/venv/bin/pip freeze --local my module shows up. which python and which pip both point to ~/venv/bin  My error is  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_module.class_file'; 'my_module' is not a package. I'm running my python code from the downloads folder. I'm going to look into it before asking a new question

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a setup.py setup file in your library

Step 1: Activate your virtual environment.

Step 2: Navigate to your library source folder.

Step 3: Install the library usually with 'python setup.py install'.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this article](https://github.com/pypa/packaging.python.org/blob/main/source/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments.rst):

1. Activate the virtual environment:

   ```
    source your_virtual_env/bin/activate
   ```
2. Go to the library folder that you would install:

   ```
    cd /path/to_your_library
   ```
3. Run command:

   ```
    python -m pip install .
   ```

If there is no error during building from source, you will get the package installed in your virtual environment.